# Upload the customer's image while registering in a zen-cart application

Tags: file-upload, zen-cart

How can we upload an image while registering the customer in zen-cart?
I would like to provide an option to upload the customer's image on registering with a zen-cart application. Is there a plug in for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that I've heard of. You would need to extend the customer_info table to hold the image file name, add an extra field to the account creation page and then handle the uploaded file in the account creation pages includes/modules/pages's header_php.php file.

However, there is a Zen Cart file upload class that provides an easy to use toolset for the last step. The admin banner page offers a good example to copy from.